# Adding new addresses for Muncipality

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-geocoding-api

We are one of the municipality in Canada and want to add our rural addresses to Google maps. So user can type the rural address and find out the location on Google Maps. Anybody knows what is the process to add all these addresses to Google Geo-coding, will appreciate for your help.

Thanks,
PM

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google Map Maker](http://mapmaker.google.com) is a tool that allows public users to add, modify and remove data from the Geo repositories at Google. User edits made in Map Maker are subject to community and internal  Google moderation before flowing into production systems.

You can read about Map Maker tool [here](https://support.google.com/mapmaker#topic=3180752).

Google also has a [Base Map Partner Program](https://maps.google.com/help/maps/mapcontent/basemap/). Using this program and [registering as a partner](https://support.google.com/mapcontentpartners/contact/mapcontent?hl=en) the local authority can submit a data in one of supported formats via Basemap Upload Tool.

You can read about supported formats at

https://support.google.com/mapcontentpartners/topic/24789?hl=en 
https://support.google.com/mapcontentpartners/answer/144284?hl=en&ref_topic=22146

There is also a help center that explains all aspects of the Basemap Partner program:

https://support.google.com/mapcontentpartners#topic=21600

Comment: Thank you for the detail info, looks we can add our data now.